# Excel formula to calculate time in h:mm

Tags: excel-formula

I have a worksheet that I would fill out the start time and end time of each call I take. I have a formula that subtracts the ending from beginning and gives me the answer in minutes [`(=TEXT(F19-F18,"h:mm")`]

At the end of the worksheet, I need to have the total time in H:mm (hours and minutes) for all calls I took for that day. I have not been able to figure out that formula.

Here's the URL to the document: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B736153457021E58!23078&authkey=!AKlwags48IPKfto&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delta, F19-F18, is the fraction of one day that the call took. Here's what you can do:

- Change this formula [=TEXT(F19-F18,"h:mm"] to [=F19-F18]
- Change the format of that cell to h:mm with a number format.
- To get the total time, sum up the column of deltas to produce a value that can also be numerically formatted to h:mm.